# Phonegap Store files in app's relative path

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugins

I am downloading and extracting zip file from a remote location. I want to extract and move these files to a location inside this app's root folder because all the images and other elements are accessing these files using (HTML-like) relative path like:

`<img src='/images/img.png'/>`

How can I perform this?

PS: Im using Phonegap and HTML5 based hybrid mobile app for android.